# Zoo Triggers, Structure & MSM Issue

Tags: multi-site-manager, structure, zoo-triggers

I have MSM setup for 2 sites. One site uses Structure and I have implemented Zoo Triggers for category functionality for a blog. All is working as it should.

The second site does not use MSM but has a blog that uses categories.

I am unable to get categories working in the second site using regular EE categories or Zoo Triggers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We had a similar issue - the 1.2.5 update fixed this for us :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new version of Zoo Triggers (1.2.5) on devot:ee which should fix this issue.

Comment: I updated but am still having the issue. Does the site not using Structure still need to use Zoo Triggers for the categories or should the native EE categories work?

Comment: I tried to change the native EE categories over to Zoo Triggers and sort of got it working. The problem I have now, is every time I click to filter by a new category, the URL structure keeps adding to itself. For example, I click a category for the first time and it works as expected giving me http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/category/category-name-here. When I click another category, it gives me http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/category/blog/category/another-category-name-here. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Never mind. It got that worked out with the path variable. Just needed to use the absolute path.

Comment: It's all working now with Zoo Triggers. Thanks!